# SameTest using in summation over a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list

```
list00 =
{ E^(-0.6830132/t), E^(-0.6830131/t), E^(-0.6830134/t), E^(-0.68301335/t),  
  E^(-0.18301321/t),E^(-0.18301341/t), E^(-0.1830133/t) , E^(0.183013/t), 
  E^(0.1830132/t) ,E^(0.6830132/t)};
```

Actually I want to have a summation result as:`4E^(-0.683013/t)+3E^(-0.183013/t)+2E^(0.183013/t)+E^(0.683013/t)`

In fact the numbers are in another list

```
list =
 {-0.6830132, -0.6830131, -0.6830134,-0.68301335,  
 -0.18301321, -0.18301341, -0.1830133 , 0.183013, 0.1830132 ,0.6830132};
```

I have used of `Sum[E^(list[[k]]/t),{k,Length[list]})]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just round the result, and then they are the same number.

```
Total[E^(Round[list, 10.^-6]/t)]
(* 4 E^(-0.683013/t) + 3 E^(-0.183013/t) + 
 2 E^(0.183013/t) + E^(0.683013/t) *)
```

The `Exp` and `Round` function are listable, so you don't need an explicit call to `Sum`.  But if you wanted one,

```
Sum[ E^(Round[list[[k]], 10.^-6]/t), {k, Length[list]}]
```

**Edit** You can also use `SetPrecision`

```
Total@Exp[ SetPrecision[list, 6]/t] 

(* 4 E^(-0.683013/t) + 3 E^(-0.183013/t) + 
 2 E^(0.183013/t) + E^(0.683013/t) *)
```

But I don't see an equivalent to `SameTest` for `Plus`

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {-0.6830132, -0.6830131, -0.6830134, -0.68301335, -0.18301321, \
-0.18301341, -0.1830133, 0.183013, 0.1830132, 0.6830132};
```

To use of Mean of the values in each cluster

```
Tr[Length[#]*E^(Mean[#]/t) & /@ GatherBy[list, Round[#, 10^-6] &]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
uni = Union[list, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-4 &)]
```

[image]

```
Total[Range[Length@uni, 1, -1] E^(uni/t)]
```

[image]

Comment: besides thanks for answer but I cannot use of Union in general. Union lessens my elements. It is true for this case only, because my coefficients are 4...3...2...1 but for a general case I cannot use of Union!!!